# Unable to make both accordian buttons display their respective content

Tags: html, css

I need the two tabs to be able to display their respective contents independently (currently, the first one has to be displayed in order for the second to display its content. How can I get these two buttons to display their respective content independently of the other?

```
<div id="Exams">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="Exams">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exam_schedule" style="width:100%;">Exam Schedule</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#practise_exams" style="width:100%;">Practise Exams</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="exam_schedule" class="collapse">
  <!-- exam schedule content -->
</div>

<div id="practise_exams" class="collapse">
  <!-- practise exams content -->
</div>
```

Comment: you want accordion or tab pills ?

Comment: Really, either is fine

Comment: The bootstrap js is included in my code (not here, but it is locally)

Comment: I had however asked you the origin of your css. And it is only now that you indicate that it is Bootstrap, this is important information that you should have mentioned in your question  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I mentioned it was from bootstrap awhile ago...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below sample code for the accordion with button

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    <p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possible problem i found in the code is not including the js file. To use Collapse functionality you need to include `jQuery.js popper.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` all three files are necesary for the implementaion of collapse. If you have included these files then make sure that they are running otherwise try using CDNs.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="Exams">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="Exams">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exam_schedule" style="width:100%;">Exam Schedule</button>
<div id="exam_schedule" class="collapse">
   exam schedule content
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#practise_exams" style="width:100%;">Practise Exams</button>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="practise_exams" class="collapse">
   practise exams content 
</div>
```